# to find scanner sdk that scan barcode details

Tags: iphone, ios

I search many scanner sdk like Zbar, scanner-kit, Red Laser, Zzing but all of them scan just barcode no one scan product details like manufacturer and product type. can any one suggest me which scanner sdk give me details? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Based on barcode number you need to fetch those details from the database.. so you need to implement your own logic.. no such details are included in barcodes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can't really get those detail from the barcode.

Barcode is just a number which you can use to with product with, for example ISDN bar code will allow you to retrieve a book via Amazon.